# Some problem of UINavigationController's parentViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch

navController is class of UINavigationController, I add it to  a view whose controller is uiviewcontroller1:

[uiviewcontroller1.view addSubview:navController.view];

Now, my question is whose is the navController's parentViewController?

(uiviewcontroller1 != navController.parentViewController) is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [parentViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController) in the tabbar, navigation and modal view context.

But, adding it's view directly to some other view, seems like you did without notify anything to the `navController`.

So, I think it's nothing wrong with `(uiviewcontroller1 != navController.parentViewController)`. Actually, `navController` shouldn't know anything about `uiviewcontroller1` at all, and stay the same as before you add it's subview to `unviewcontroller1`.